# DataGrid Column Width string to width converter MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, converters

Right now I have a combobox with multiple different entries and when selected I want a datagrid I have to change column width according to the selected text from the combobox. So far I have tried using a converter within a style under my window resources, however, the width of my columns are not changing according to the entered text but set back to Auto instead. Here is my converter:

```
public class BindingWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var Notation = value as string;
        if (Notation == null) return 26;
        switch (Notation)
        {
            case "size 1":
                return 26;
            case "size 2":
                return 40;
            case "size 3":
                return 45;
            case "size 4":
                return 50;
            case "size 5":
                return 60;
            default:
                return 26;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And here is how it is defined under my XAML window.resource:

```
<Style x:Key="ElementStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding NotationType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, IsAsync=True, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource WidthConv}, ConverterParameter=0}"/>
</Style>
```

This is then entered into my DataGrid.Column portion:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="0" Binding="{Binding DataSpace, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, IsAsync=True, Converter={StaticResource DataConv}, ConverterParameter=0}"
    ElementStyle="{StaticResource ElementStyle}" 
    CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle0}" 
    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}"/>
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the width converter in the DataGrid width itself and not the TextBlock?

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="0" 
     Binding="{Binding DataSpace, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, IsAsync=True, Converter={StaticResource DataConv}, ConverterParameter=0}"
     ElementStyle="{StaticResource ElementStyle}"
     Width="{Binding NotationType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, IsAsync=True, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource WidthConv}}"
     CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle0}" 
     HeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}"/>
```

I assumed that  `NotationType` is a Property from the same item as `DataSpace`.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: NotationType is a property different from dataspace, it is the selectedvalue binding of a combobox within the same grid so i used                                               Width="{Binding Path=NotationType, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid} , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, IsAsync=True, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource WidthConv}}" instead, and it still defaults to auto and not the values put in.